an isometry preserving an equilateral triangle will preserve its vertices

Prove that an isometry preserving an equilateral triangle will
preserve its vertices, i.e if $\Delta ABC$ is an equilateral triangle
and $f$ is an isometry s.t $f(\Delta ABC)=\Delta ABC$ then
$\{A,B,C\}=\{f(A),f(B),f(C)\}$.

I already knew that the image of a triangle is a triangle congruent to the original triangle. Since isometries preserve distance, then $AB = A'B', AC = A'C',$ and $BC = B'C'$. Therefore by SSS triangle $ABC$ is congruent to triangle $A'B'C'$.
But how can I prove $\{A,B,C\}=\{f(A)=A',f(B)=B',f(C)=C'\}$. Any help would be appreciated.

Isn’t this given in the problem statement?  Suppose it weren’t.  Then f(ABC) would not equal (ABC), which is a contradiction.

Seems you accept $f(\Delta ABC)$ is a triangle with vertices $f(A),f(B),f(C).$ (I questioned this when I first saw your question.) If so you are asking: If $\Delta ABC = \Delta DEF$ why do the two triangles have the same vertices? This must be part of the definition of equal for two triangles.

What about a rotation by 120° about the center of the triangle?

@Intelligenti pauca then either $f(A)=B$, $f(B)=C$, and $f(C)=A$ or $f(A)=C$, $f(C)=B$, and $f(B)=A$.  It is know that an isometry of the plane is the composition of at most three reflections.

Just observe that the vertices are the only three points of the triangle having a distance between each pair equal to the side.
